# RQuantLib: any difference between FixedRateBond() and FixedRateBondPriceByYield() with flat term structure?

Tags: fixed-income, r, yield-curve, bond, quantlib

Please, consider the following functions from `RQuantLib` package:

- `FixedRateBond()`
- `FixedRateBondPriceByYield()`

Is there any difference in the final output if one uses the former specifying a flat term structure, e.g.

```
params <- list(tradeDate = as.Date(’2002-2-15’),
               settleDate = as.Date(’2002-2-19’),
               dt = .25,
               interpWhat = "discount",
               interpHow = "loglinear")
               setEvaluationDate(as.Date("2004-11-22"))
               discountCurve.flat <- DiscountCurve(params, list(flat = 0.05))
```

instead of the latter with `FixedRateBondPriceByYield(..., yield = 0.05, ...)`?
(Use the same parameters at `...`).

`FixedRateBondPriceByYield()` should just return bond's clean price, while `FixedRateBond()` can return dirty price in addition to accrued interests and cash flow tables.

Anything else?

Comment: have you tried simply checking the output in response to each call? is that not the best first step one way or another?